# TypeScript file type check

Tags: angular, typescript, file-type

I have modified code based on [this tutorial](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/show-image-preview-before-uploading-using-angular-7/) to display uploaded images in an angular project.

```
public uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
      this.imgURL = reader.result; 
    }
}
```

This works fine, the only thing is, I also want to check if the file is a video.
Is the correct syntax

```
mimeType.match(/video\/*/)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: https://help.encoding.com/knowledge-base/article/correct-mime-types-for-serving-video-files/

Below you can fine full mime types

```
Flash           .flv    video/x-flv
MPEG-4          .mp4    video/mp4
iPhone Segment  .ts     video/MP2T
3GP Mobile      .3gp    video/3gpp
QuickTime       .mov    video/quicktime
A/V Interleave  .avi    video/x-msvideo
Windows Media   .wmv    video/x-ms-wmv
```